# blender model looks messy in libgdx since I added armature and animation

Tags: animation, model, libgdx, blender

my blender model meanwhile looked fine in libgdx.
But after I added an armature and and animation, the rendering in libgdx became a mess. The upper part of the model looks still good, the lower not. I animated both, the upper and the lower part.

Can somebody explain me, what the cause could be?

By the way, it's a human figure you see below. The blue something are the legs.

[image: http://imageshack.com/a/img600/7201/4z1r.png]

Comment: not sure but someone postet such a few days ago. Moving the camera a bit more out of the scene solved it if i remember that right.

Comment: maybe that was my post as well, but that was another issues. Moving the camera helped with the perspective, but here the legs are not recognizable as legs anymore..
Meanwhile I made another simple model with only 3 bones. That works well.And I read in the manual of the G3D Exporter that all bones have to be normalized. Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: As much as i know G3D is deprecated you should use G3DJ for debug (.json format, easy to read) and G3DB for the real game (binary, faster to load?).